# Slugify via helper or store slug on database?

Tags: concepts, knowledge

I have a simple question: **Slugify via helper or store the [slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28web_publishing%29#Slug) on database?**

I mean, let's suppose that I have `Guilherme Oderdenge` on database and I want to transform it into a human-readable URL such as `http://myapp.com/guilherme-oderdenge/`, what's the best way to perform this? Storing  `guilherme-oderdenge` in the database or transforming `Guilherme Oderdenge` in a slug with a helper like `user.name.slugify`?

I know there are some ways to reach the expected result, but which one is better? Or at least there is a better way?

#### It depends of the technology that you're using

-
I'm using Ruby On Rails with MySQL.

Comment: what do slug / slugify mean?

Comment: I really want to know about -1.

Comment: @gnat its what they call making a human readable but still valid URLs.  So instead of a url like "/article/blog?id=3534546", it'd be "/article/gnats_blog"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would store the slug in the database, this gives you the flexibility of being able to customize your slug if the logic to create a slug didn't create a desirable slug.

Also, if you had 2 pages with the same name, you would want to have two different slugs as they probably should be unique.

Thirdly this represents a good separation of concerns, the database if for querying data, not creating content.

Just to clarify, I recommend you create the slug in your app code, and store that in the db.

Comment: Perfect explanation and you convinced me. Thank you, that's enough for now.